# Access Phonegap API from Backbone.js model

Tags: backbone.js, cordova, requirejs

I'm developing an app with backbone.js, require.js and Phonegap. I'm having problems accessing the Phonegap api from the Model. My index.html file looks like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
<link href="topcoat/css/topcoat-mobile-light.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/pageslider.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
<script data-main="js/app" src="js/require.js"></script>
</head>

<body></body>

</html>
```

In the initialize function of the router, I'm testing the Phonegap API:

```
    initialize: function() {


        window.localStorage.setItem("key", "some bloddy value");
        var value = window.localStorage.getItem("key");

        console.log('the value is');
        console.log(value);
}
```

This works fine, I can get that the value is set and is retrieved. I also have a logged in status model. This is as follows:

```
define(function (require) {

"use strict";

var $                   = require('jquery'),
    Backbone            = require('backbone'),


    LoginStatus = Backbone.Model.extend({

        defaults: {
           loggedIn: false,
           api_key: null,
           user_id: null
       },

       initialize: function () {

        window.localStorage.setItem("key2", "some other value");
        var value = window.localStorage.getItem("key2");
        console.log('in init, the value is');
        console.log(value);
       },

    });

return {
    LoginStatus: LoginStatus
};

});
```

When I call instantiate model from the initialize function of the router, I get the error:

```
Uncaught illegal access at file:///android_asset/www/js/app/models/loginstatus.js
```

How can I access Phonegap api from my models?

Comment: By `initialize` function of the router do you mean a Backbone.Router?
Are you making sure this initialize function is executed after phonegap's `deviceready` event is triggered?

Comment: Yes, its in the Backbone.Router. I'm not triggering deviceready - how do I do this?

Comment: You should add an event listener to `deviceready` event. Inside the listener you should start the backbone router. In that way you start using phonegap API when everything is ready.

`document.addEventListener("deviceready", function(){
  Backbone.history.start();
}, false);`

Comment: Thank you, that worked. Can you out as the answer?

Comment: You're welcome. I posted it as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add an event listener to deviceready event. Inside the listener you should start the backbone router. In that way you start using phonegap API when everything is ready.

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", function(){ 
    Backbone.history.start(); 
}, false);
```